# what is the right way to achieve 'notification' in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React, and I use Angular before. so when I need to send a notification from one component to another(for example, click a button in a pop-up window and passing data to another component and that component will do something like refresh page), and they're barely related(not parent & child). and I don't want to use props passing data. In angular, I can use Rxjs(BehaviorSubjec) to achieve this. but I don't know how to do this in React. Can someone help me?

Comment: I answered your question, but since it's a generic topic, feel free to ask more specific questions if you have in mind

Comment: ...but components have common top-level parent (root)? or separate apps within window?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle state management and side effects in React.
The goto library for state management in React is [redux](https://redux.js.org/) which is a popular implementation of [Flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)
For doing side effect things there are many libraries to name a few [Redux saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/), [Redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)